# Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type DESPITE null-coalescing operator

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, nullable, .net-7.0

I'm still quite new to C# (about 4months in) and I don't understand why this would be an issue.

[Run on DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSyFlq)

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

public class Test{  
    public static void Main(){
        var json = @"{""key"": ""value""}";
        
        var node = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json);
        
        if( node is null ){
            return;
        }
        
        foreach( var property in node ){
            var key = property.Key;
            var val = (string) (property.Value?? "" ); // warning
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {val}");
        }
    }
}
```

The line

```
var val = (string) (property.Value?? "" );
```

raises the warning

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

[The C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) says specifically:

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result. The ?? operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

This leads me to the conclusion, that the content of the parantheses `property.Value?? ""` can never be null. Yet the warning seemingly suggests otherwise.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your goal you can use:

```
var val = property.Value?.ToString() ?? "" ;
```

Or

```
var val = property.Value?.ToJsonString() ?? "" ;
```

The problem with the warning seems to be that `property.Value?? ""` internally uses [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) from `string` to `JsonNode?` and compiler does not understand that the resulting value is always not null ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8e9a17b2216f51a5788f8b1c467a4cf3b769e7d7/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonNode.Operators.cs#L197)). I assume that it could be fixed in .NET 8 where it is marked with corresponding attribute:

```cs
[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(value))]
public static implicit operator JsonNode?(string? value) => JsonValue.Create(value);
```